# Complex XML into SSRS Report

Tags: sql, xml, reporting-services

I have this complex xml where the schema is not known.  There can be any number of children and in any order. The order needs to be preserved.

e.g. 
Flow components can have 50 Classification points with other sections before and after it.

I would like to extract each section with attribute values into a ssrs report. A simple tree structure will be enough. Will be greatful for any help. 
-XML link from my gdrive --
[XML File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw_rOz2NTzAuZEdCc1J6cTJNZVk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shredding XML From Execution Plans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39347880/shredding-xml-from-execution-plans)

Comment: Hi Abe, look [at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39347880/5089204) There you'll find a straight approach with `FROM OPENXML` and a great function to shredd an unknown XML down to a tree

Comment: Thank you all I am going to try the above links. I tried it with the xml in question and I am able to generate a sql table.  I need to traverse the table to get all child nodes etc.  Thanks once again.

Comment: the approach with `FROM OPENXML` is very fast and allows you to traverse the tree on your own (read about *recursive CTE*). The given function is a great piece of code returning a lot of helpful *meta-data*... Happy Coding!

Comment: The above solution works perfectly fine. I created a list in SSRS and grouped by parent and got just what i wanted to see in the report.  Thanks once again to one and all.