# OPENXML Leaves out xml rows that do not have the specified elements

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am running below query on SQL Server 2014 server but I can't understand why I am getting only one row in result.

```
DECLARE @idoc int, @doc varchar(1000);   

SET @doc ='  
<ROOT>  
<Customer CustomerID="VINET" ContactName="Paul Henriot">  
   <Order CustomerID="VINET" EmployeeID="5" OrderDate="1996-07-04T00:00:00">  
      <OrderDetail OrderID="10248" ProductID="11" Quantity="12"/>  
      <OrderDetail OrderID="10248" ProductID="42" Quantity="10">
                    <ReturnDetail ReturnOrderID="1111" ReturnDate="1996-08-04T00:00:00"/>
            </OrderDetail>  
   </Order>  
</Customer>  
<Customer CustomerID="LILAS" ContactName="Carlos Gonzlez">  
   <Order CustomerID="LILAS" EmployeeID="3" OrderDate="1996-08-16T00:00:00">  
      <OrderDetail OrderID="10283" ProductID="72" Quantity="3"/>  
   </Order>  
</Customer>  
</ROOT>';  

--Create an internal representation of the XML document.  
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @doc;   

-- SELECT stmt using OPENXML rowset provider  
SELECT *  
FROM   OPENXML (@idoc, '/ROOT/Customer/Order/OrderDetail/ReturnDetail',2)   
         WITH ( OrderID       int         '../@OrderID',   
                order_CustomerID  varchar(10) '../../@CustomerID',   
                EmployeeID  varchar(10) '../../@EmployeeID',
                ContactName  varchar(100) '../../../@ContactName',
                CustomerID  varchar(10) '../../@CustomerID',
                OrderDate   datetime    '../../@OrderDate',   
                ProdID      int         '../@ProductID',   
                Qty         int         '../@Quantity',
                ReturnOrderID int '@ReturnOrderID',
                ReturnDate datetime '@ReturnDate'
                );
```

[image: Output by above query]

How do I get all 3 records returned like below

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You should use the **built-in, native XQuery** support (instead of the legacy `OPENXML` stuff...).

Use this code to get all the details down to the `<OrderDetail>` node (define your `@doc` variable as **`XML`**):

```
DECLARE @doc XML;

SET @doc = '......';

SELECT
    OrderID = XOD.value('@OrderID', 'int'),
    CustomerID = XCus.value('@CustomerID', 'varchar(20)'),
    ContactName = XCus.value('@ContactName', 'varchar(50)'),
    EmployeeID = XOrder.value('@EmployeeID', 'int'),
    OrderDate = XOrder.value('@OrderDate', 'datetime'),
    ProductID = XOD.value('@ProductID', 'int'),
    Quantity = XOD.value('@Quantity', 'int'),
    ReturnOrderID = RetD.value('@ReturnOrderID', 'int'),
    ReturnDate = RetD.value('@ReturnDate', 'datetime')
FROM
    @doc.nodes('/ROOT/Customer') AS XT(XCus)
CROSS APPLY
    XCus.nodes('Order') AS XT2(XOrder)
CROSS APPLY
    XOrder.nodes('OrderDetail') AS XT3(XOD)
OUTER APPLY
    XOD.nodes('ReturnDetail') AS XT4(RetD)
```

For each "level" that might contain *multiple nodes* (like `<Customer>` under `<ROOT>` etc.), you need to use `CROSS APPLY` and the `.nodes()` XQuery function to get all the child nodes - not just one (first or arbitrary).

Comment: You were faster :-), +1 from my side. You might add `ReturnOderID=XOD.value('(ReturnDetail/@ReturnOrderID)[1]','int')
` in order to get the values of the lower `ReturnDetail` node (which are  - probably - not 1:n)

Comment: @Shnugo: **excellent!** That last tip saved my day! :-) Thanks, man!

Comment: Hi, I just checked your edit and found how you were struggeling with the `INNER JOIN`-like behaviour of `CROSS APPLY`. It was the same (and even better in case of `1:n`) to use `OUTER APPLY`. This would behave like `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks guys! Are u indicating that OPENXML will be deprecated in future versions? I specifically wanted use OPEN XML as I was creating a generic XML to row converter in TSQL. The input XML may or may not come with same number of elements/attributes each time; and the client is not happy to hear that we might have to recode in those instances. However, you answer helped me in fixing my original query `code        ReturnOrderID int 'ReturnDetail/@ReturnOrderID',
        ReturnDate datetime 'ReturnDetail/@ReturnDate'`

Comment: @JayeshPrakash [Read this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39347880/5089204) about shredding an unknown XML generically. There is one answer (by me) pointing to `OPENXML`, which has some very rare but still usefull areas and a great function using "modern" approach. Might be, that this function is all you need...