# Parse XML to Table in SQL (Only nodes that have values)

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xml-parsing, xquery

I am trying to find a way to parse a rather large XML file into a table that simply shows the name of the node, and it's value. There are no attributes to worry about in the XML, but there are several nested nodes.

Because there the XML is generated dynamically, there is no way of knowing the exact depth of that nesting. But it is safe to assume only the **LAST CHILD NODE** of any branch will contain data.

This is my attempt at a solution, but the problem is that when accessing a parent node, the data from every child within gets concatenated as the value.

```
DECLARE @ProjectXML XML
SET @ProjectXML = '
<Project>

  <ProjectId>1</ProjectId>
  <OrganizationId>1</OrganizationId>
  <Title>This is a Test Title</Title>
  <Description>This is a Test Description</Description>
  <ProjectType>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Name>Test Name</Name>
    <Outer>
        <Inner1>Hi</Inner1>
        <Inner2>There</Inner2>
    </Outer>
  </ProjectType>
</Project>
'
SELECT
n.value('local-name(.)','VARCHAR(100)') AS Name,  
n.value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)') AS Value

FROM @ProjectXML.nodes('//*') AS ProjectXML(n)
```

Which results in:

```
Project           11This is a Test TitleThis is a Test Description1Test NameHiThere
ProjectId         1
OrganizationId    1
Title             This is a Test Title
Description       This is a Test Description
ProjectType       1Test NameHiThere
Id                1
Name              Test Name
Outer             HiThere
Inner1            Hi
Inner2            There
```

Is there a way (using xquery perhaps?) to ignore the parent nodes which contain no data, and only return values for the child nodes which do?

**Bonus points if it is possible to return the Name of each result as a formatted list of it's parent nodes , such as:

```
Project - ProjectId                         1
Project - OrganizationId                    1
Project - Title                             This is a Test Title
Project - Description                       This is a Test Description
Project - Project Type - Id                 1
Project - Project Type - Name               Test Name
Project - Project Type - Outer - Inner1     Hi
Project - Project Type - Outer - Inner2     There
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a peek at http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/28/posts/10495/xquery-lab-58-select-from-xml.aspx

```
Select * from XMLTable(@ProjectXML) where value is not null
```

Returns more than you may want, but you can tailor to your needs

[image]

Comment: You just saved me at least 3 days worth of pulling my hair out. This worked perfectly, The "FullPath" and "Value" columns were exactly what I needed. I ran this against my large XML files, and everything went smoothly. I can't thank you enough!

Comment: @JustinTrenary I was pleased when I stumbled upon that one.  I'm ashamed to admit what my attempt looked like.  I made some dramatic tweaks in my instance, but didn't want to take credit for his work.  BTW I gave you the Plus1 because it was a good, and well formed question.  I would be thrilled if all new members half the job you did.

Comment: I'd be curious, what your *ashaming attempts* looked like :-) I just posted an answer with a quite simple `XQuery`... Anyway +1 for your honesty :-)

Comment: @Shnugo You should keep "Office Hours" or even 1-900-XML-HELP

Answer (score 2):

This could be done much easier...

It is a bit tricky to get the `/text()` of a node if there is no `/text()`. But there is the `empty()`-function and the `not()`-function:

```
SELECT
n.value('local-name(.)','VARCHAR(100)') AS Name,  
n.value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)') AS Value
FROM @ProjectXML.nodes('//*[not(empty(text()))]') AS ProjectXML(n)
```

And you might [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39347880/5089204)

The old `FROM OPENXML` with `WHERE text IS NOT NULL` would deliver the same plus more details about the position within the XML.

But the linked function by John Capelletti is great. Just stick with this...